# Dynamic Flex Workflow in Studio

Tags: twilio-studio

As part of my Twilio Studio flow I am using the HTTP request step to get data from an external database that responds back with the agent skill to be used when routing the call however I am unable to figure out how to use this variable in the send to flex step. Is it possible to dynamically set the workflow in the send to flex step from a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution passing Json in the send to flex step and using filters at the workflow level.